# Rust RSA implementation with weird behaviours

Tags: algorithm, rust, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I've implemented a very basic Rust implementation of the RSA algorithm. All seems to work nice, but I've found a strange behavior with the encryption/decryption process on my testing. Because it works 3/4 times, which is really weird..

The library can be found here: https://github.com/CPerezz/rust-rsa

Here is the code:

**math.rs** (Each of the functions have been tested and passed)

```rust
//! Math functions to build keys with trusted primes
use std::str::FromStr;
use rand::Rng;
use num_bigint::{ToBigUint, BigUint, RandBigInt, BigInt, Sign};
use num::{Zero, One, Integer, FromPrimitive};
use crate::helpers::generics::*;


// Generates a big number of lenght = u32 param.
pub fn gen_big_num(bit_len: &u32) -> BigUint {
    // RNG depends on rng_core crate.
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut a = rng.gen_biguint(bit_len.to_owned() as usize);
    a
}

// Given lenght, generates a prime number of that lenght approximately.
// That prime number is prime with probability = 4^-threshold 
pub fn gen_big_prime(size: &u32, threshold: u32) -> BigUint {
    let mut proposal =  gen_big_num(size);
    // Remove all even numbers to reduce the iterations a half.
    if proposal.is_even() {
        proposal = proposal + BigUint::one();
    }
    while !is_prime(&proposal, threshold) {
        // Steps of 2 to avoid the even numbers on the iterations.
        proposal =  proposal + 2.to_biguint().unwrap();
    }
    proposal
}

// Posible to remove and implement it on gen big prime
// Given a prime proposal, compute Rabin Miller's algorithm.
fn is_prime(proposal: &BigUint, threshold: u32) -> bool {
    if !rabin_miller(proposal, threshold) {return false}
    true
}

// Rabin-Miller is a probabilistic algorithm that checks if a number is prime based on Riemmann's conjecture.
// Implemented from psoudocode found on: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Primality_Testing 
// The function recieves a prime proposal and the threshold probability of a false positive
// due to composite numbers reported as primes.
// The pobability of a false positive is 4^-threshold. With t=9 => P(false_positive) = 3/1_000_000 
fn rabin_miller(proposal: &BigUint, t: u32) -> bool {
    // Needed constants
    let (z, o, tw) = gen_basic_biguints();
    let (zero, one, two) = (&z, &o, &tw);
    // If proposal <= 1 Rabin-Miller has to fail.
    if proposal.clone() <= one.to_owned() {return false};
    // If proposal != 2 and modulus 2 = 0, Rabin-Miller fails.
    if proposal.clone() != two.to_owned() && proposal.clone() % two == zero.to_owned() {return false};
    // Getting exp to execute mulmod.
    let (s,d) = refactor(proposal);

    let mut counter = 0;
    while counter < t {
        // Gen rand biguint from a range (2, proposal-2)
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        let a = rng.gen_biguint_range(&two , &(proposal - two) );

        let mut x = mod_exp_pow(&a, &d, proposal);
        if x != one.to_owned() && x != proposal.to_owned() - one {
            let mut i = zero.clone();
            loop {
                x = mod_exp_pow(&x, &two, proposal);
                if x == proposal.to_owned() - one {break;}
                if x == one.to_owned() || i >= s.clone()- one{return false;};

                i = i.clone() + one;
            }
        }
        counter +=2;
    }  
    true
}

// Modular exponentiation implemented on binary exponentiation (squaring)
pub fn mod_exp_pow(base: &BigUint, exp: &BigUint, md: &BigUint) -> BigUint {
    let mut res = BigUint::one();
    let (zero, one, _) = gen_basic_biguints();
    let (mut base, mut exponent) = (base.clone(), exp.clone());

    while exponent > zero {
        if exponent.clone() & one.clone() > zero {
            res = (res * base.clone()) % md;
        }
        // Shifting 1 bit of the exponent as a binary number.
        exponent >>= 1;
        // Generating next base by squaring
        base = (base.clone() * base.clone()) % md;
    }
    res
}

// Given a number n, write n − 1 as 2s·d with d odd by factoring powers of 2 from n − 1
fn refactor(n: &BigUint) -> (BigUint, BigUint) {
  let (mut s, one, two) = gen_basic_biguints();
  let mut d = n.clone() - one.clone();

  while d.is_even() {
    d = d / two.clone();
    s = s + one.clone();
  }
  (s, d)
}

// Extended Euclidean Algorithm
// Returns gcd(a,b) and Bézout's identity coefficients
// ax + by = gcd(a,b)
pub fn egcd<'a>(a: &'a mut BigInt, b: &'a mut BigInt) -> (BigInt, BigInt, BigInt) {
    // base case
    if a.to_owned() == BigInt::from(0 as u32) {
        (b.clone(), BigInt::from(0 as i32), BigInt::from(1 as i32))
    } else {
        let mut b_mod_a = b.clone() % a.clone();
        let ref_b_mod_a = &mut b_mod_a;
        let (g, x, y) = egcd(ref_b_mod_a, a);
        let mut b_div_a = b.clone() / a.clone();
        let ref_b_div_a = &mut b_div_a;
        (g, (y - ref_b_div_a.clone() * x.clone()), x)
    }
}

// Given a fi_n, find on the interval (fi_n/2, fi_n) a number 
// that is co-prime with fi_n
pub fn found_e(fi_n: &BigUint) -> Result<BigUint, bool> {
    // Gen random number on interval
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    //Get fi_n as 
    let sign = Sign::Plus;
    let mut fi_n = BigInt::from_biguint(sign, fi_n.clone());
    let (zero, one, two) = gen_basic_bigints();
    let mut a = rng.gen_bigint_range(&(fi_n.clone()/two.clone()) , &((BigInt::from(3) * fi_n.clone())/BigInt::from(4) ));
    //We want to avoid the even random numbers.
    if a.is_even() {a = a + one.clone()};
    let mut res = zero;
    while res != one.clone() && a <= fi_n.clone() - one.clone() {
        let (res2, _, _) = egcd(&mut fi_n, &mut a);
        res = res2;
        a = a.clone() + two.clone(); 
    }

    if res == one {
        a = a.clone() - two.clone();
        return Ok(biguint_from_bigint(&a));
    }
    Err(false)
}


#[test]
fn generates_random_biguint() {
    let a = gen_big_num(&1024);
    assert_ne!(a, BigUint::zero());
}

#[test]
fn mod_exp_works() {
    let res = mod_exp_pow(&BigUint::from(4 as u32), &BigUint::from(13 as u32), &BigUint::from(497 as u32));
    assert_eq!(res, BigUint::from(445 as u32));

    let res2 = mod_exp_pow(&BigUint::from(5 as u32), &BigUint::from(3 as u32), &BigUint::from(13 as u32));
    assert_eq!(res2, BigUint::from(8 as u32));
}


#[test]
fn rabin_miller_works() {
    //Small primes
    let res = rabin_miller(&179425357u32.to_biguint().unwrap(), 9);
    assert_eq!(res, true);
    let res2 = rabin_miller(&82589933u32.to_biguint().unwrap(), 64);
    assert_eq!(res2, true);


    // Big primes
    let known_prime_str =
    "118595363679537468261258276757550704318651155601593299292198496313960907653004730006758459999825003212944725610469590674020124506249770566394260832237809252494505683255861199449482385196474342481641301503121142740933186279111209376061535491003888763334916103110474472949854230628809878558752830476310536476569";
    let known_prime: BigUint = FromStr::from_str(known_prime_str).unwrap();
    assert!(rabin_miller(&known_prime, 64));
}


#[test]
fn gen_big_prime_works() {
    let res = gen_big_prime(&2056u32, 9);
    println!("The generated prime of 1024 bits is: {}", res);
}

#[test]
fn egcd_test() {
    use num_bigint::ToBigInt;
    use std::str::FromStr;

    // small primes
    let a = &mut 179425357u32.to_bigint().unwrap();
    let b = &mut 97u32.to_bigint().unwrap();
    let (g, x, y) = egcd(a, b);
    assert_eq!(a.clone()*x + b.clone()*y, g);

    // small primes
    let a = &mut 1024u32.to_bigint().unwrap();
    let b = &mut 512u32.to_bigint().unwrap();
    let (g, x, y) = egcd(a, b);
    assert_eq!(512u32.to_bigint().unwrap(), g);

    // big primes
    let known_prime_str = "118595363679537468261258276757550704318651155601593299292198496313960907653004730006758459999825003212944725610469590674020124506249770566394260832237809252494505683255861199449482385196474342481641301503121142740933186279111209376061535491003888763334916103110474472949854230628809878558752830476310536476569";
    let known_prime_str_2 = "357111317192329313741434753596167717379838997101103107109113127131137139149151157163167173179181191193197199211223227229233239241251257263269271277281283293307311313317331337347349353359367373379383389397401409419421431433439443449457461463467479487491499503509521523541547557563569571577587593599601607613617619631641643647653659661673677683691701709719727733739743751757761769773787797809811821823827829839853857859863877881883887907911919929937941947953967971977983991997";
    let mut a: BigInt = FromStr::from_str(known_prime_str).unwrap();
    let mut b: BigInt = FromStr::from_str(known_prime_str_2).unwrap();
    let a_r = &mut a;
    let b_r = &mut b;
    let (g, x, y) = egcd(a_r, b_r);
    assert_eq!(a_r.clone()*x + b_r.clone()*y, g);
}
```

And here the types where encryption and decription is made:

```rust
use num_bigint::{BigUint, BigInt, ToBigInt, Sign};
use crate::helpers::math::*;
use crate::helpers::generics::*;
use num::{Signed, One};
use std::fmt;
use std::ops::Neg;
use std::str::{FromStr, from_utf8};

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct KeyPair {
    pub pk: PublicKey,
    pub sk: SecretKey,
    pub size: u32,
    pub threshold: u32
}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct PublicKey {
    n: BigUint,
    e: BigUint
}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct SecretKey {
    n: BigUint,
    d: BigUint
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq)]
pub struct Threshold {
    value: u32
}

impl Threshold {
    // Creates a Threshold with a default error probability of generating a prime of 4^-64
    pub fn default() -> Self {
        let threshold = Threshold {
            value: 9 as u32
        };
        threshold
    }

    // Creates a Threshold with a selected value as thresholf of P(err). P(err prime) = 4^-threshold. 
    pub fn new(th: &u32) -> Self {
        let th = Threshold {
            value: *th
        };
        th
    }

    // Gets the value of a Threshold and returns it as u32.
    pub fn value(th: Self) -> u32 {
        th.value
    }
}


// Implementation of Display for KeyPair Struct.
impl fmt::Display for KeyPair {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "\nPublic Key: \n{}\nSecret Key: \n{}\nSize: {}\nThreshold: {} which gives a P(err_primes_gen) = 4^(-{})", self.pk, self.sk, self.size, self.threshold, self.threshold)
    }
}

impl KeyPair {
    // Generate a new KeyPair Struct from scratch by giving the size of the key desired (in bits) and the threshold of P(err) while assuming that
    // a number is prime. Statistic methods are used to found that numbers. P(err) = 4^-threshold (As is demonstraded on the Rabin-Miller algorithm)
    pub fn new(size: &u32, threshold: &Threshold) -> Result<Self, &'static str> {
        // Gen basic needed variables
        let (_, one, _) = gen_basic_biguints();
        // Gen p q primal base
        let p = gen_big_prime(size, threshold.value);
        let q = gen_big_prime(size, threshold.value);
        // Gen n and fi_n
        let n = &p * &q;
        let fi_n = (&p - &one) * (&q - &one);
        // Find a positive integer minor than fi_n , co-prime with fi_n 
        let e = found_e(&fi_n).unwrap();

        // Building Pk Struct
        let pk = PublicKey::new(&n, &e).unwrap();
        // Finding d and building Secret Key Struct
        let (_, _,mut d) = egcd(&mut fi_n.to_bigint().unwrap(), &mut e.to_bigint().unwrap());
        if d.is_negative() {
            d = d.neg();
        }
        let sk = SecretKey::new(&n, &biguint_from_bigint(&d)).unwrap();
        //Building KeyPair struct
        let kp = KeyPair {
            pk: pk,
            sk: sk,
            size: size.to_owned(),
            threshold: threshold.value.to_owned()
        };
        // Return the KeyPair struct
        Ok(kp)
    }
}



// Implementation of Display for KeyPair Struct.
impl fmt::Display for PublicKey {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "n: {}\ne: {}", self.n, self.e)
    }
}

impl PublicKey {
    // Generate a PublicKey struct from n and d co-prime factors.
    fn new(_n: &BigUint, _e: &BigUint) -> Result<Self, &'static str> {
        Ok(PublicKey {
            n: _n.to_owned(),
            e: _e.to_owned()
        })
    }
    // Generate a PublicKey struct from n, fi_n and d params with the co-prime property checking.
    fn new_from_fi_n_e(_n: &BigUint, _fi_n: &BigUint, _e: &BigUint) -> Result<Self, &'static str> {
        let (_, _one, _) = gen_basic_bigints();

        match egcd(&mut BigInt::from_biguint(Sign::Plus, _fi_n.to_owned()), &mut BigInt::from_biguint(Sign::Plus, _e.to_owned())) {
            (possible_one, _, _) => {
                if possible_one.is_one() {
                    return  Ok(PublicKey {
                                n: _n.to_owned(),
                                e: _e.to_owned()
                            }
                        )
                }else {
                    return Err("Params passed to Sk builder haven't the properties to be a Public Key")

                }            
            }
        }
    }
    // Encrypts the data passed on the params.
    fn encrypt(&self, msg: &str) -> Result<&str, &'static str> {
        if !msg.is_ascii(){
            return Err("Message isn't ASCII like. Please remove non-ASCII characters.")
        }else{
            println!("Message as bytes: {:?}", msg.as_bytes());
            let res = BigUint::from_bytes_be(msg.as_bytes());
            println!("COPRIMES IF ONE ---->>  {:?}", egcd(&mut BigInt::from_biguint(Sign::Plus, res.clone()), &mut BigInt::from_biguint(Sign::Plus, self.n.clone())).0);
            Ok(string_to_static_str(format!("{}", mod_exp_pow(&res, &self.e, &self.n))))
        }
    }
}


// Implementation of Display for KeyPair Struct.
impl fmt::Display for SecretKey {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "n: {}\nd: {}", self.n, self.d)
    }
}

impl SecretKey {
    // Generate a SecretKey struct from n and d co-prime factors.
    fn new(_n: &BigUint, _e: &BigUint) -> Result<Self, &'static str> {
        Ok(SecretKey {
            n: _n.to_owned(),
            d: _e.to_owned()
        })
    }

    // Generate a SecretKey struct from n, fi_n and d params with the co-prime property checking.
    pub fn new_from_fi_n_e(_n: &BigUint, _fi_n: &BigUint, _d: &BigUint) -> Result<Self, &'static str> {
        let (_, _one, _) = gen_basic_bigints();

        match egcd(&mut BigInt::from_biguint(Sign::Plus, _fi_n.to_owned()), &mut BigInt::from_biguint(Sign::Plus, _d.to_owned())) {
            (possible_one, _, _) => {
                if possible_one.is_one() {
                    return  Ok(SecretKey {
                                n: _n.to_owned(),
                                d: _d.to_owned()
                            }
                    )
                }else {
                    return Err("Params passed to Sk builder haven't the properties to be a Public Key")

                }            
            }
        }
    }

    // Decrypts the cyphertext giving back an &str
    fn decrypt(&self, text: &str) -> Result<&str, &'static str> {
        let c = BigUint::from_str(text).unwrap();
        let result_as_bytes = mod_exp_pow(&c, &self.d, &self.n).to_bytes_be();
        println!("C as bytes: {:?}", result_as_bytes);
        let res_decrypt = std::str::from_utf8(&result_as_bytes).unwrap();
        Ok(string_to_static_str(format!("{}", res_decrypt)))
    }
}
```

The thing is that when I run the test:

```rust
#[test]
fn encrypts_decrypts_info(){
    let kp = KeyPair::new(&512u32, &Threshold::new(&10)).unwrap();
    let msg = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non nunc et ipsum tempus fermentum";
    let cyphertext = kp.pk.encrypt(msg).unwrap();


    let res_decrypt = kp.sk.decrypt(&cyphertext).unwrap();
    println!("Result of decryption is: {}", res_decrypt);
    assert_eq!(res_decrypt, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non nunc et ipsum tempus fermentum")
}
```

When the test gives an error I get this:

```
running 1 test
Message as bytes: [76, 111, 114, 101, 109, 32, 105, 112, 115, 117, 109, 32, 100, 111, 108, 111, 114, 32, 115, 105, 116, 32, 97, 109, 101, 116, 44, 32, 99, 111, 110, 115, 101, 99, 116, 101, 116, 117, 114, 32, 97, 100, 105, 112, 105, 115, 99, 105, 110, 103, 32, 101, 108, 105, 116, 46, 32, 80, 114, 97, 101, 115, 101, 110, 116, 32, 110, 111, 110, 32, 110, 117, 110, 99, 32, 101, 116, 32, 105, 112, 115, 117, 109, 32, 116, 101, 109, 112, 117, 115, 32, 102, 101, 114, 109, 101, 110, 116, 117, 109]
COPRIMES IF ONE ---->>  BigInt { sign: Plus, data: BigUint { data: [1] } }
C as bytes: [61, 207, 34, 84, 216, 183, 90, 189, 50, 169, 219, 109, 65, 100, 222, 105, 115, 8, 229, 173, 114, 40, 162, 83, 121, 184, 99, 167, 157, 98, 165, 91, 226, 140, 203, 84, 185, 161, 137, 201, 231, 132, 35, 112, 96, 89, 32, 253, 249, 175, 57, 133, 235, 65, 230, 250, 50, 142, 54, 70, 123, 203, 51, 145, 82, 129, 249, 79, 236, 30, 107, 210, 49, 139, 232, 69, 248, 48, 108, 215, 234, 223, 51, 88, 64, 223, 218, 54, 117, 137, 136, 226, 166, 144, 96, 111, 203, 239, 121, 129, 158, 21, 191, 227, 119, 79, 109, 124, 103, 204, 243, 143, 86, 60, 19, 162, 247, 253, 96, 150, 49, 134, 41, 94, 58, 122, 89, 44]
thread 'types::encrypts_decrypts_info' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Utf8Error { valid_up_to: 1, error_len: Some(1) }', src/libcore/result.rs:1009:5
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
stack backtrace:
   0: std::sys::unix::backtrace::tracing::imp::unwind_backtrace
             at src/libstd/sys/unix/backtrace/tracing/gcc_s.rs:49
   1: std::sys_common::backtrace::_print
             at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:71
   2: std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}
             at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:59
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:211
   3: std::panicking::default_hook
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:227
   4: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:491
   5: std::panicking::continue_panic_fmt
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:398
   6: rust_begin_unwind
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:325
   7: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at src/libcore/panicking.rs:95
   8: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/9fda7c2237db910e41d6a712e9a2139b352e558b/src/libcore/macros.rs:26
   9: <core::result::Result<T, E>>::unwrap
             at /rustc/9fda7c2237db910e41d6a712e9a2139b352e558b/src/libcore/result.rs:808
  10: rsa_rust::types::SecretKey::decrypt
             at src/types.rs:191
  11: rsa_rust::types::encrypts_decrypts_info
             at src/types.rs:217
  12: rsa_rust::types::encrypts_decrypts_info::{{closure}}
             at src/types.rs:211
  13: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/9fda7c2237db910e41d6a712e9a2139b352e558b/src/libcore/ops/function.rs:238
  14: <F as alloc::boxed::FnBox<A>>::call_box
             at src/libtest/lib.rs:1471
             at /rustc/9fda7c2237db910e41d6a712e9a2139b352e558b/src/libcore/ops/function.rs:238
             at /rustc/9fda7c2237db910e41d6a712e9a2139b352e558b/src/liballoc/boxed.rs:673
  15: __rust_maybe_catch_panic
             at src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:102
test types::encrypts_decrypts_info ... FAILED
```

So at this point, idk if the error is coming from a bad key generation or a bad bytes encoding/decoding process.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does the situation when your code doesn't work happen when the most significant bit of the modulus is set or the most significant bit of private exponent is set? Numbers would then be considered negative

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that the decrypted buffer ("C as bytes" in your traces) is not valid UTF-8, so `str::from_utf8` fails. If I understand your code correctly "C as bytes" should be the same as "Message as bytes", since it isn't I assume that there is a bug in your encryption or decryption code, but I can't tell you which.